# MFC Rich Edit TOM -- InsertTable; cannot add more than one column?

Tags: winapi, mfc, rtf, richtext

May you please help, I can only insert a table with any number of rows, but not columns; I get an E_INVALIDARG when cols > 1 in ITextRange2::InsertTable(cRow,cCol,AutoFit)??

```
IRichEditOle* pREOle = NULL; // rCtrl is my derived CRichEditView in MFC
HRESULT hr = rCtrl.SendMessage(EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0,
(LPARAM)&pREOle);
CComQIPtr<ITextDocument2> pITextDoc;
hr = pREOle->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ITextDocument2), (void*)&pITextDoc);
CComPtr<ITextRange2> range;
pITextDoc->Range2(start, start, &range);
hr = range->InsertTable(3,3, 1); // get hr = E_INVALIDARG here
```

Comment: Could you provide us with your test environment? hr = pREOle->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ITextDocument2), (void*)&pITextDoc); IRichEditOle is an incomplete class type for me

Comment: Have you tried passing 0 for `AutoFit`? Also which version of RichEdit control are you using?

Comment: Hey Guys - I figured this out after a few days and help from someone from MS Docs. The solution is rather windows APIish

Comment: If you have resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Below is code, that will insert a table for editing rows or inserting a new table. The function is declared in my derived view class CMHMView. I added fields such as ITextRange2* m_ptr2, HRESULT m_hr.

Initialization is done in my CRichEditView::OnInitialUpdate:

```
CRichEditCtrl& re = GetRichEditCtrl();
m_pREOle = re.GetIRichEditOle();
m_hr = m_pREOle->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_ptd2));
```

This is the function I use to add the table(s)

```
void CMHMView::InsertTableRow(long index, long& start, long& end, long ncells, 
long cellwidths[], long skip, LPCTSTR* sText, BOOL bAppend){

if (SUCCEEDED(m_hr))
{
    long lDelta{};

    CComPtr<ITextFont> pFont;

    m_hr = m_ptr2->GetFont(&pFont);

    CComPtr<ITextRow> pRow;
    CComPtr<ITextFont> pFontDuplicate;

    m_hr = m_ptr2->GetRow(&pRow);
    m_hr = pFont->GetDuplicate(&pFontDuplicate);

    if (pRow && pFontDuplicate)
    {
        CComPtr<ITextPara> pPara, pParaDuplicate;
        m_ptr2->GetPara(&pPara);
        pPara->GetDuplicate(&pParaDuplicate);

        pFontDuplicate->SetName(CComBSTR(L"Courier New"));
        pFontDuplicate->SetSize(12.0f);

        m_ptr2->MoveStart(tomTable, start, &lDelta);
        m_ptr2->Collapse(tomEnd);
        if (bAppend)
        {
            pRow->SetCellCount(ncells);
            for (int i = 0; i < ncells; i++)
            {
                pRow->SetCellIndex(i);
                pRow->SetCellWidth(cellwidths[i]);
            }

            pRow->Insert(1);
            m_ptr2->SetIndex(tomTable, index, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < skip; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                    m_ptr2->MoveStart(tomCell, 1, &lDelta);
                m_ptr2->SetText(CComBSTR(L""));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < ncells; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                    m_ptr2->MoveStart(tomCell, 1, &lDelta);

                m_ptr2->SetText(CComBSTR(sText[i]));
                m_ptr2->SetFont(pFontDuplicate);
                m_ptr2->SetPara(pParaDuplicate);

            }
            
            m_ptr2->EndOf(tomTable, tomMove, &lDelta);

            
            m_ptr2->GetEnd(&end);
        }
        else
        {           
            m_ptr2->SetText(CComBSTR(L"\r"));
            m_ptr2->Collapse(tomEnd);

            pRow->SetCellCount(ncells);
            for (int i = 0; i < ncells; i++)
            {
                pRow->SetCellIndex(i);
                pRow->SetCellWidth(cellwidths[i]);
                /*pRow->SetCellMergeFlags(tomHStartCell)*/
            }

            pRow->Insert(1);
            m_ptr2->SetIndex(tomTable, index, 0);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < ncells; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                    m_ptr2->MoveStart(tomCell, 1, &lDelta);

                m_ptr2->SetText(CComBSTR(sText[i]));
                m_ptr2->SetFont(pFontDuplicate);
                m_ptr2->SetPara(pParaDuplicate);

            }
            
            m_ptr2->EndOf(tomTable, tomMove, &lDelta);              
            m_ptr2->GetEnd(&end);
        
        }
    }
}
m_pREOle->Release();}
```

I hope this will help others!